# if (!empty ($_POST)) not working

Tags: php, post

I have this form and have issues with my $_POST data not coming through:

Form:

```
<form action="" id="contact-form" method="post">

           <input id="nombre" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">

           <input id="email" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Email">

           <textarea id="texto"></textarea>

           <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

PHP:

```
<?php

 if(!empty($_POST) {

 echo "YES";

 } else {

 echo "NO";

 }

?>
```

It always echoes "NO" when I complete and submit all the fields.

Comment: you need to specify `name` attribute for you input fields

Comment: You should also check your syntax, you 're missing the closing parenthesis on the `if` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `name` attribute of the input fields. Change your html and add them:

```
<form action="" id="contact-form" method="post">
    <input id="nombre" name="nombre" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
    <input id="email" name="email" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    <textarea id="texto" name="texto"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Note that the `id` attribute is not required. You can omit it if you don't need it for other purposes like using it in a stylesheet or in javascript. For simply sending the form just the `name` attribute is required

Comment: Ohh my goodness .. it's so simple and right in front of my eyes ... I'm a newby as you should realize.. hehe .. thanks very much . .everyone for helping me..  :)

Comment: Level complete. Go forward to the next error! :) Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want a specific field, try:

```
if(isset($_POST['field']{0})){
```

If you want to check for multiple fields POST, try:

```
if(count($_POST)>0){
```

Comment: always an idiot who only come here to earn `score` and why the other negative responses. The only reason would be to help and share, and not be up with Importing `score`.

Comment: Sorry Guilherme ... I can't do anything about it... I have no voting rights yet ... but it's incredible that there's so stupid people in a website that is suposed to be used to help other people rather than take them down ...  your answer is valid too .. I've just tried it...

Comment: Thanks for responding to my comment.
I really do not care about the votes, but not to worry it is not your responsibility. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your input should have the `name` attribute set, which sets them in $_POST array. `id` is ignored in posting forms!

```
<input id="nombre" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre">
```

and you will get it in $_POST['nombre']

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution ,if you add ***"name"*** attribute to your inputs , it should work:

```
 if (count($_POST) == 0)  {

         echo "YES";
    }
  else {

         echo "NO";

       }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify a variable, so  `$_POST['email']` for example. For all of the fields try;

`if(!empty($_POST['Nombre']) && !empty( $_POST['email']) && !empty ( $_POST['texto'])) { ...`

Sorry I'm on a mobile device, such a pain to get all the spelling correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (empty($_POST['qty'])) {
    echo "<script>alert('inputan Quality tidak boleh kosong');history.go(-1);</script>";
} 
else {
    ...
}
```

so no validation error, here I use array